# What does major dev =0 means in /proc/pid/maps

Tags: linux, proc

an example for /proc/pid/maps

```
0022a000-00245000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 11633540   /lib/ld-2.5.so
00245000-00246000 r--p 0001a000 ca:01 11633540   /lib/ld-2.5.so
00246000-00247000 rw-p 0001b000 ca:01 11633540   /lib/ld-2.5.so
00249000-003a3000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 11633640   /lib/i686/nosegneg/libc-2.5.so
003a3000-003a5000 r--p 0015a000 ca:01 11633640   /lib/i686/nosegneg/libc-2.5.so
003a5000-003a6000 rw-p 0015c000 ca:01 11633640   /lib/i686/nosegneg/libc-2.5.so
003a6000-003a9000 rw-p 003a6000 00:00 0 
00ada000-00adb000 r-xp 00ada000 00:00 0          [vdso]
08048000-08049000 r-xp 00000000 00:16 4735574    /home/yimingwa/test/Ctest/link_test/SectionMapping.elf
08049000-0804a000 rw-p 00000000 00:16 4735574    /home/yimingwa/test/Ctest/link_test/SectionMapping.elf
b7fcf000-b7fd0000 rw-p b7fcf000 00:00 0 
b7fe1000-b7fe2000 rw-p b7fe1000 00:00 0 
bfe82000-bfe98000 rw-p bffe8000 00:00 0          [stack]
```

the 4th column means  “If the region was mapped from a file, this is the major and minor device number (in hex) where the file lives”

In the above, ca:01 I can find through /proc/devices /dev

**Question is that what does "00：16"  00 means which major device?**